# Is it possible to subclass UITableView and make it have an intrinsic content size for its height based on the number of cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I want my `UITableView` to only be as tall as it needs to be, as it floats above the main `UIViewController`'s `view`. If I hardcode a height of 200 and theres' only one cell in the table, it looks silly.

I'm aware in my view controller I could monitor the table view and define the height of it based on the number of cells it has, but the height is a property of the view, and for MVC it doesn't make much sense for the controller to be actively managing a view's height.

Is it possible to have a `UITableView` subclass, and have it define an intrinsic height based on the number of cells it holds? So with Auto Layout I could add the subclass to my view, specify its width, center it vertically, and perhaps define a "less than or equal" height constraint saying to keep it smaller than 200pts.  But for the most part have the intrinsic content size of the view define the height of the view automatically?

This would be just like a `UILabel` being able to be centered horizontally and vertically with some distance from the left and right, and have it grow and shrink vertically automatically.

Could I feasibly do this with a `UITableView` subclass?

Comment: Why do you oppose to let the VC tell the view the max available space? That's perfectly valid and done by iOS all the time by providing the bounds for a view.

Comment: @dogsgod Because under the MVC paradigm I'd prefer to leave the view to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily by having the table view use its contentSize property to "know" how tall it needs to be. This value could be somewhat inaccurate if you're using estimated row heights, but it should be good enough. In this example, I gave the table view a height constraint (as well as width and centerY), and made an IBOutlet to it (heightCon). The only code needed was this,

```
@interface RDTableView ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightCon;
@end

@implementation RDTableView

-(void)reloadData {
    [super reloadData];
    self.heightCon.constant = MIN(200, self.contentSize.height);
}
```

You would also have to override reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: and 
reloadSections:withRowAnimation: if you're updating your table with either of those as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you (re)load data in your `TableView`, you can do this. The `TableView` will take only the height it needs

```
CGRect frame = youTableView;
frame.size.height = CELL_HEIGHT*[yourArray count];
if(frame.size.height > MAX_TABLEVIEW_HEIGHT)
{
    frame.size.height = MAX_TABLEVIEW_HEIGHT
}
youTableView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a chicken/egg problem you have with designing your UI. Sounds like you want to set the height of the floating tableview based on how many rows it contains * height per row, but the tableview doesn't know any of this information until its been drawn, ie [tableView reloadData] and the corresponding height for row delegate methods are called.

I'd suggest rendering the tableview offscreen somewhere, draw all the rows, sum up all the heights for each row, then present the view to the user with the appropriate CGRect.